# on Ubuntu colored multiline PS1 in bash works wrong with arrow up history

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-prompt, ps1

I have next line in `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\e[0;32m[ \w ]\n#\e[m "
```

to set very simple welcome line of green color. On Ubuntu using arrow up/down to load previous commands puts extra symbols to the command line:

```
[ /tmp ]
# echo "hello there"
hello there
[ /tmp ]
# echecho "hello there"
```

Notice `ech` symbols in front of last command. These symbols can't be edited -- cursor doesn't go there.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape the characters that are not displayed. Change the line in `.bashrc` to the following:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;32m\][ \w ]\n#\[\e[m\] "
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes.